# Python If Condition not executed, only else condition is processed

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am relatively new to python, but not to programming. The If condition is getting incorrectly processed, and the 'else' part is printed:

```
if self.health_points <= -1 and self._foo__is_dead  == False:
    print("Enemy Terminated")
else:
    print("Enemy is  dead")
```

I printed out the 2 variables, and they make the condition to true for input of '14'. Still, why is the else part being executed?
Please, may I know where am I going wrong?

```
class Enemy:
 health_points = 5
 _foo__is_dead = False

 def set_hp(self,points_to_set):
    if self._foo__is_dead == False:
        self.health_points = points_to_set
    else:
        print("Enemy is already dead")

 def attack(self):
    print("Hit confirmed")
    self.health_points -= 1

    if self.health_points <= -1:
        self._foo__is_dead = true

    print(self._foo__is_dead)
    print(self.health_points)

    if (self.health_points <= -1 and self._foo__is_dead  == False):
        print("Enemy Terminated")
    else:
        print("Enemy is  dead")

 #Connected to pydev debugger (build 172.3968.37)
 #Enter hit points for first enemy14
 #Hit confirmed
 #False
 #13


 def reveal_hp(self):
    if self._foo__is_dead == False:
        print(self.health_points, " health points remaining")
    else:
        print("Enemy is already dead")


first_enemy = Enemy()

try:
 one_hp = int(input("Enter hit points for first enemy"))
except ValueError or one_hp > 100:
 print("Enter only numerical values and less than 100")
 exit(0)

first_enemy.set_hp(one_hp)
first_enemy.attack()
first_enemy.reveal_hp()
```

Comment: If only the else is running, that means your condition is always false. Are you sure `_foo__is_dead` is what you think it is? Also, keeping a separate flag to keep track of death seems overly complicated. It seems simpler to just define an `isDead` that is defined in terms of the health value.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: The `else` part is getting executed because the first clause (negative HP) is false (HP = 13 at that point).  This is how `if` statements work.  Where are you confused?

Comment: ' self._foo__is_dead' in the if condition is evaluating to 'False'. Also, it's not `true`, but `True` in the logic

Comment: Oh! that was really phenomenally absent-minded of me.!
Caught my silly mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't thought out the logic quite correctly. Currently you have it set so that if the enemy has zero health and isn't dead, then say they've been killed. If not, say they're already dead, even if they have health remaining. You just need to add in that final check.

It should work correctly for you if you swap this:

```
if (self.health_points <= -1 and self._foo__is_dead  == False):
    print("Enemy Terminated")
else:
    print("Enemy is  dead")
```

For something like this:

```
if self.health_points <= -1:
    if not self._foo__is_dead:
        self._foo__is_dead = True
        print("Enemy Terminated")
    else:
        print("Enemy is  dead")
else:
    print("Enemy has {} health remaining".format(self.health_points))
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. That worked perfectly.
May I know the flaw with my logic?
What was happening with my code?

Comment: Found my issue.!
Thanks for your help.